# Android Edit Text must contain two letters and three numbers

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to limit what information can be entered into an edittext field. I want the edit text to take two letters only, followed by three numbers, for example: CM066. I've tried using:

```
InputFilter myFilter = new InputFilter() { 
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 


                        if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) { 
                                return ""; 
                        } 

                        if (i == start) {
                           return source.toUpperCase();
                        }

                } 
                return source; 
        } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{myFilter});
```

However I think this only allows one or the other. Is there a way to do this? or would it be easier to have these as two edit texts and set the input types in XML? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
private void codeFilter()
    {
        codeInput.setFilters(new InputFilter[]
                {
                new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)
                {
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                               int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend)
                    {
                        if (src.toString().matches("[A-Z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]"))
                        {
                            return src;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: your answer is not correct. is also takes CM006545555555 as correct input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this kind of checking. For your case when you want to allow only two letters then three digit regular expression is

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$
```

If you allow Upper hand letter only then it should be

```
^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$
```

You can use it like below

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("CM006");
if(m.matches())
{
 //do what you want to do
}
else
{
 //do if they dont match
 }
```

If you want to learn more about regular expression and pattern in android

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html